# Junit spark: what is the equivalent of assertDataFrameEquals in java to compare 2 dataframes

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, junit

I need to compare 2 dataframes in my unit test using java, i know that in scala we have assertDataFrameEquals but i didn't found the equivalent in java or how to compare 2 dataframes in junit.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

assertDataFrameDataEquals is also available in java from [spark-testing-base](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.holdenkarau/spark-testing-base)
You need to import *JavaDataFrameSuiteBase* (in Scala it is just *DataFrameSuiteBase*)

`import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.JavaDataFrameSuiteBase;`

The main thing in java you need to create an object for JavaDataFrameSuiteBase to access the methods. So you can use assertDataFrameDataEquals as below. This is using junit and spark-testing-base.

```
@Test
public void personsComputeTransformTest() {

// read personsInputDf(input) and call your function to be tested to get personsResultDf(result)

JavaDataFrameSuiteBase javaDataFrameSuiteBase = new JavaDataFrameSuiteBase();
javaDataFrameSuiteBase.assertDataFrameDataEquals(personsInputDf, personsResultDf);

}
```

Comment: another alternative is https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-fast-tests